# How do I check if a button was clicked on a form in html and run some code in nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I need some help as Im new to nodejs and trying to make one of my goals at the moment. I want to send some data to a MySQL database with the information I put into a form. I can figure out how to make it when I click the button on the form to make it do something in nodejs.

```
<button id='send' class="btn btn-success"><a style="color: white;" href="Main.html">Send</a></button>
```

How can I make it run a function or something. Please and thank you.

Comment: If the button is in a form, you don't need to anything on the client-side, as clicking the button submits the form to your server. Notice, that the URL to submit the form to is defined in `action` attribute of the form, not in a `href` attribute of the button.

Answer (score 0):

The Best way to do these task you need to use **axios** calls
****Axios is a very popular JavaScript library you can use to perform HTTP requests, that works in both Browser and Node.js platforms.**
It is promise-based, and this lets us write async/await code to perform XHR requests very easily.**
Using Axios has quite a few advantages over the native Fetch API:

#supports older browsers (Fetch needs a polyfill)

#has a way to abort a request

#has a way to set a response timeout

#has built-in CSRF protection

#supports upload progress

#performs automatic JSON data transformation

#works in Node.js

Comment: Actually, I haven't seen a single library which would be easier to use than the native XHR object ...